# How to add a breaking row that my auto fil formula shuld not run after that row?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I my Excel sheet, I have more than 200 thousand rows data in multiple columns, once I use "fill down" option to a column, that fills the entire column (more than 1 million) with the fourmula and the PC will start hanging.
So I need to set a cell or row line which breaks the foumula from auto filling after that cell or row.

[image]

Here you can see the empty active cell also filled with the formula and it is running out of the boundary. So I need to stop running the formula when I use "fill down" option after 268,425th row.
How can I do that?

Comment: Up to `50,000` row you can use `BYROW()` function.

Comment: use a table (insert >> table) - formula will fill only used range

Comment: @Ike I have more than 120 columns .. each column has different amount of rows .. it's very difficult to convert all to pivot tables .. any other methods ?

Comment: not a "pivot table", but a "table" !